# coalesce function in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I have written the following query in SQL Server which is performing slow in time of execution:

```
select * from  Orders where OrderId='01' 
order by coalesce(OrderDeliveryDate, convert(datetime,OrderEstimatedDate)) desc
```

I think the execution of the query is slow due to use of coalesce function.Can I write the query in some other way to minimize execution time?

Comment: Have you tried it without? Also, isn't `OrderEstimatedDate` already of type `datetime`?

Comment: Don't guess at why it's slow - generate an execution plan and see where it's spending its time. I'd be seriously surprised if that's the source of the slowness, in and of itself.

Comment: The convert in your order by is going to seriously hurt performance here. Also, is OrderId a varchar or is it a number? Also limiting the columns returned could help performance. There is no reason to return every column in more queries.

Comment: Why do you need to convert `OrderEstimatedDate`? Is this not a `datetime` column?

Comment: Is your orderID field really a string?

Comment: How many fields are in the `Orders` table? What indexes are defined on the table? Using `SELECT *` is not going to be as efficient as specifying a few fields, especially if all are contained within an index. How many rows in the table? How many rows do you expect back? What do you consider "slow"?